# Error when I try write in list -language C

Tags: c, list, malloc

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
typedef struct NBIG{
    int number;
    struct NBIG *nseg;
    struct NBIG *nant;
}Nbig;   
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    char *namefile,ch;
    Nbig *new_node=NULL,*resmulti=NULL,*ofsum=NULL;
    Nbig *list=NULL;
    int cont,x,y;
    FILE *arq;

    if (argc>3) {
        for(cont=3; cont < argc; cont++){

            namefile =strcat(argv[cont], ".txt");
            printf("%s", namefile);
            arq = fopen(namefile, "r");
            if(arq == NULL)
                printf("Fail\n");
            else{
                fseek(arq, -1, SEEK_END);
                long position = ftell(arq);
                while(position >= 0){
                    fseek(arq, position, SEEK_SET);
                    fread(&ch, sizeof(char), 1, arq);
                    if (ch == ' ') {
                        ofsum=soma(ofsum, list);
                        list = delete_list(list);
                        new_node = delete_list(new_node);
                        position = position-1;
                    } 
                    else{
                       new_node =makenode();
                       new_node->number= atoi(&ch);
                       list =insertfirst(list, new_node);
                       position--;
                       show(list);
                       printf("\n");
                    } 
                }
                show(ofsum);
                printf("\n");
                fclose(arq);
            }

        }
    }
    else{
    ...
    }
return 0;
}
```

In file:
(the numbers are separated by 1 space)
Example:
123 123

I try execute the program and return this:

1

21

321

agrv(28381,0x7fff8f271380) malloc: *** error for object
 0x7f814bc026c0: pointer being freed was not allocated *** set a
 breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

How do I solve the problem?
I introduce 3 arguments in execution

```
Nbig *makenode(){
    Nbig *R = (Nbig*)malloc(sizeof(Nbig));
    R->number=0;
    R->nant=NULL;
    R->nseg=NULL;
    return(R);
}
Nbig *delete_list(Nbig *L) {
    if(L==NULL){
       return L;
    }
    Nbig *next;
    while (L) {
        next = L->nseg;
        free(L);
        L = next;
    }
    return NULL;
}




Nbig *insertfirst(Nbig *A,Nbig *nv){
    if(A==NULL){
        nv->nseg=NULL;
        nv->nant=NULL;
        return nv;
    }
    nv->nseg=A;
    A->nant=nv;
    return nv;
}
```

Function adicional

Comment: your code is unreadable :/

Comment: After you do `free(L);` you access `L->nseg` on the next iteration of the `while` loop. That's undefined behavior.

Comment: And after the loop is done, you do `free(L)`. That will try to free the same thing that you freed on the last iteration of the loop.

Comment: the posted code causes the compiler to output several warnings messages.  Several of those warning messages are critical.  When compiling always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) separate code blocks ( `for` `if` `else` `while` `do...while` `switch` `case` `default` ) via a single blank line.  2) separate functions by 2 or 3 blank lines (be consistent)  3) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: for flexability (and readability) the definition of a struct should be separated from a typedef for that struct.

Comment: variable (and parameter) names should indicate `usage` or `content` (or better, both).  names like `nf` `ch` `vem` etc are meaningless, even in the current context

Comment: you should never change the `argv[]` array.  This line: `nf=strcat(argv[cont], ".txt");` is trying to change the `argv[]` array.

Comment: this code block: `if(arq == NULL)
                printf("Fail\n");`  is executed if the call to `fopen()` fails. Later, after the end of the `else` code block is `fclose(arq);` which would be trying to close a file that was never opened.

Comment: regarding: `if (ch == 32)`  Using the numeric value for characters makes the code unnecessarily difficult to read.  Suggest using: `if (ch == ' ')`

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) insert an appropriate space; inside parens, inside brackets, after commas, after semicolons, around C operators.

Comment: in C, the returned type from `malloc` `calloc` `realloc` is `void*`  That can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc.

Comment: this code block: `while (L->nseg!=NULL)
      {
        L=L->nseg;
        free(L);
      }` is freeing the current Nbig, then using that same pointer to access a field in the (already freed, so not available) current node.  This is undefined behavior. then the next code: `free(L);`  frees the already freed Nbig node.  This is undefined behavior

Comment: the `insertFirst()` will not work correctly when there is more than 1 instance of Nbig already in the `lista`

Comment: given your explanation of the contents of each of the input files, the method of stepping back through the file contents is not correct

Comment: i edit the code but the problem persists

Answer (score 1):

Your loop for freeing the list is wrong. You're freeing the current element `L`, then using `L->nseg` on the next iteration. Deferencing a pointer after freeing it is undefined behavior.

You need to save the `nseg` pointer *before* you free the current element.

It should be:

```
Nbig *apaga(Nbig *L) {
    Nbig *next;
    while (L) {
        next = L->nseg;
        free(L);
        L = next;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: You probably have other errors in the functions you didn't post. A common error is forgetting to initialize `nseg` to `NULL` when you create a new `Nbig` node.

Comment: but is NULL in function

Comment: Then you have other problems. Sounds like it's time for you to learn to use a debugger to step through your program.

Comment: I'm not going to try to figure out all your code. Learn to use a debugger and figure it out yourself.

Comment: Logic errors don't cause warnings, they just produce incorrect results.

Comment: i don't understand has incorrect in my code.basically what I want it to do is to add all the numbers that are in the file separated by a space. But I don't understand why don't work

Comment: Because you have a BUG. That's what debuggers are for.

Comment: I think no have erros now but the problem persists